# How to work with Lombok?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, lombok

I am trying to use Lombok jar on my project.

My main class:

```
package lombok_example;
import lombok.Cleanup;
public class Emp_Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Employee emp=new Employee();
      emp.setEmpNo("EMP1");
    }
}
```

My bean class:

```
package lombok_example;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class Employee {
    private String empNo;
    private String empName;
    private String empAddress;
}
```

I am trying to set a value at *empNo*, but can't find any setter method for this. How can i set value in the particular bean?

Comment: Code is ok. If you want IDE help, you need to install lombok plugin to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue might be Lombok is not installed properly.

Try to re-install the lombok.

If you are using eclipse then restart the eclipse. [Link](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)

If you are using Intelij, then follow this [link](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij)

Answer (score 0):

Install plugin for your IDEA.

Lombok add the byte code .